# Newbie in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I want to start learning Assembly language, but I don't know where to start. I know that Assembly is dependent upon architecture of the processor. So I have one question on the spot. **If I write some assembly code on my system, is it likely to not work in another computer? If not, how Windows or Linux is created, so it works on almost all computers. Or am I wrong?**

Comment: Are you talking about the source or the executable?

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting to learn assembly? Do you know some higher-level languages and feel you need assembly for some reason?

Comment: Both Linux and Windows were written in C, not assembly.

Comment: Wanting to start off learning assembly is kind of like going to the Neurosurgery forum and asking how do you get started with a career in Neurosurgery. My understanding of it (I dont know assembly) is that it is the language used by the microprocessor itself so I would assume there are differences in programming for different chips. I dont believe its O/S related.

Comment: It's actually not too dumb to learn assembly fairly early in ones programming career.  I can say for a fact that learning C and other pointer-rich languages is far easier if you already know the basics of assembler/machine language.  (After all, C is just high-level assembly. ;))

Comment: What you might want to do is to search the web for a good simple machine-language simulator.  (I don't know of any offhand, but I'm pretty sure there must be several.)  These let you learn the concepts without having to deal with a lot of ugly details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assembly language is the language of the processor.  Different processor, different language.

There are a number of ways to achieve [portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability).  Writing in C and then compiling your C programs on the target processor is one way.  Using virtual machines is another.

Some portability is achieved by the same *family* of processors having similar instruction sets.  So Intel and AMD processors will run the same portable assembly language code, because the instruction sets have been designed to be compatible with each other.

But a RISC processor will not run the same assembly language program, because the instruction set is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly is a very low-level language, nearly directly translated to machine code (which is a "language" understandable for the CPU). Most today's PC's are based on x86 architecture, and so the assembly for most PC's is quite similar. Differences may depend on operating system  (for example most Linux systems use different signs for end of the line than Windows) and some additional features of the specified processor (though it is same architecture, depending on the model the CPU may have some different operations available). Of course, for different architecture the assembly is different (for example: you can't compile x86 code for ARM processor, as those have entirely different instruction set available).

Operating systems are usually written in some higher-level languages and only some functionality (usually this required to be as fast as possible on a specified machine) is written in some low-level code, like assembly, for specified platforms.

To start your adventure with assembly I would reccommend 8086 assembly. It can give you some insight into how to write assembly code in general and may be a good base for learning assembly for different architectures somewhere in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly language is per ISA (Instruction Set Architecture). Examples are x86 (running on most client PCs today and a large chunk of servers), ARM (mostly used in mobiles such as smartphones or tablets, microservers, embedded systems, etc..), Alpha, IBMs' PowerPC, Itanium (mostly obsolete), etc..

Within the client segment (your home desktop or notebook which I believe you meant, belongs there), There's likely to be compatibility, this is how you can buy and run windows for x86 (there are also other versions these days), or linux or whatever, on pretty much any computer. Note that these ISAs are constantly evolving, adding new instructions and new architectural features and modes of operations - so a program designed for a new version of some ISA will likely not work on a much older HW, but since the designers struggle to maintain backward compatibility - an older SW is almost granted to work on a newer HW since the old modes and instructions are still supported. Operating systems are also changing though, so code designed for DOS will not run on a new windows "as-is", but can be run with some help from emulators and other tricks.